# Using findAll Collection Closure in Groovy

Tags: groovy, iteration

I have a "Set" that I need to use the findAll closure upon. The Set contains objects, not just primitive values. For instance... I have a Set of Employee objects and I need to iterate and grab elements of that Set of Empolyee Objects by attributes of the Employee.

For some reason the findAll closure seems to be just ignore my close and returns an empty set.

Here is my syntax;

```
dstCollection = srcCollection.findAll{
    it.age == 22
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
class Employee {
    int age

    String toString() {
        age
    }
}

def list = [ new Employee(age:22), new Employee(age:23), new Employee(age:22) ] as Set

println list
println list.findAll { it.age == 22 }
```

output:

```
[22, 23, 22]
[22, 22]
```

Can you post your code?

Edit: added "as Set", since I noticed the question is about sets and not lists. This also works for me.

Comment: You are missing a "{" on the toString definition ;-)